# Python dataframe - .astype(str).astype(int) gives error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe column from object to int using:

`df['col'].astype(str).astype(int)`

but I am getting an error

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

due to the fact that some of the elements are empty. How can I deal with that and overcome / get rid off this error?

Here is what a part of my column looks like:

```
 0001081316
 0001081316
 0001609253
 0000928022
 0000928022
 0000916457
 0000916457
 0000916457
 0000916457
 0000016732
 0001094093
 0000911177
 0000816284
 0000816284
 0000879573
 0000018808
 0000785080
 0000018926
 0000018926
 0000018926
 0000018926
 0001319048
 0001627223
 0000895126
 0000895126
 0000895126
 0000895126
 0000895126
 0000716133
 0000716133
 0000716133
 0000716133
 0000716133
 0000020520
 0000020520
 0000020520
 0000020520
 0001400891
 0001400891
 0001400891
 0000020947
 0000764065
 0000764065
 0000764065
 0000764065
 0000764065
 0000021344
 0000021344
 0000215466
 0000215466
 0001158324
 0001323653
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0001166691
 0000918040
 0000023194
 0000023217
 0001358071
 0001163165
 0001163165
 0001710366
 0000897732
 0000016918
 0000016918
 0000732834
 0000732834
 0000024741
 0001018980
 0000025305
 0000025305
 0001051470
 0001051470
 0000912513
 0000028630
 0000916540
 0000931336
 0001571996
 0000027904
 0000027996
 0001090012
 0001090012
 0001090012
 0001090012
 0000949039
 0000949039
 0000949039
 0000715957
 0000715957
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000029669
 0000030554
 0000030554
 0000030554
 0000030554
 0001326160
 0001326160
 0001092839
 0000821189
 0000821189
 0000821189
 0000821189
 0000821189
 0000821189
 0000750199
 0000033213
 0000033213
 0000915389
 0001600470
 0001066107
 0001066107
 0001590895
 0000032604
 0000032604
 0001591763
 0001591763
 0000880285
 0000880285
 0000880285
 0001161154
 0001161154
 0001161154
 0001024401
 0001024401
 0000033619
 0001532063
 0001532063
 0001532063
 0000887936
 0001062613
 0000880430
 0000880430
 0000038074
 0000038074

 0000831259
 0000831259
 0000831259
 0000831259
```

Comment: There are non-integer values in the column, try ``fillna(0)`` then apply dtype casting.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of that somehow eg convert the rest? Or maybe I could replace empty values with 0 or something.

Comment: It would be more clear if u can add some sample data.

Comment: I edited my post and added some data.

Comment: have u tried ``pd.to_numeric`` by setting ``errors='coerce'`` which will set ``NaN`` to invalid input values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that int columns are stored in int32 or int64 numpy arrays, and neither dtype has a concept of empty value. It is not an accident if an int column is converted to a floating point type as soon as you add a NaN value to it.

With recent versions of Pandas >=0.24, you can try to use the nullable integer extension dtype:

```
df['A'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['A'].isna()|(df['A']==''), pd.NA,
           df.loc[df['A']!='','A'].apply(int).reindex(df.index)
           .fillna(0)), dtype=pd.Int64Dtype)
```

But beware is is explicitely declared to be experimental:

> Note
>
> IntegerArray is currently experimental. Its API or implementation may change without warning.

Comment: I get an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nannan'` when I use this. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: You should first list the offending values with `df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['A'], 'coerce').isna(), 'A']`. Maybe you have non numeric values in the column...

Answer (score 0):

first of all fill the empty elements and then to convert them into int. It will through the above error. so first fill all empty elements in column then apply this...

```
df['col'].replace('','0',inplace=True)

df['col'].astype(int)
```

For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['1','2','4','3',''])
df.replace('','0',inplace=True)
df=df.astype('int')
```